# Glob package in Python. FIle path is append with \\ instead of /. Expecting forward slash instead of 2 backslashes

Tags: python, glob

I'm using glob API to load all my CSV into a list. After executing my code, I realize the results in data_list append \ in the file path instead of / before the csv data file name.

My python code file is in this location: C:\Documents\python-workspace\analysis.py

My 4 csv data are in this location:

1. C:\Documents\python-workspace\data\vitalstrike\user-site-export\data-1.csv
2. C:\Documents\python-workspace\data\vitalstrike\user-site-export\data-2.csv
3. C:\Documents\python-workspace\data\vitalstrike\user-site-export\data-3.csv
4. C:\Documents\python-workspace\data\vitalstrike\user-site-export\data-4.csv

Below is my code to load the files into the list

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_profiling
import glob

data_list = glob.glob('data/vitalstrike/user-site-export/data-*')
display(data_list)
```

After executing the code, I realize the results in data_list append the csv data file name with '\\' instead of '/'. Any advice how to force it to / ?

```
In[15]: display(data_list)
['data/vitalstrike/user-site-export\\data-1.csv',
 'data/vitalstrike/user-site-export\\data-2.csv',
 'data/vitalstrike/user-site-export\\data-3.csv']
```

Comment: This seems like a bit of apples and oranges problem. Why exactly do you want to use `/` instead of the local OS path separator?

Comment: Dont mix os separators, on Windows it is `\\\`, so use them in glob(...) as well.

Comment: I suppose you could force it by simply running this on any POSIX compliant (or mostly compliant) system.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I am using spyder IDE. When I display the values in the data_list on console, it display data/vitalstrike/user-site-export\\data-1.csv. When I view the value in the list directly, its a single '\'

Comment: Actually I want to append the found csv file name to the file path as /data-1.csv instead of \data-1.csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `os.path.join`, to create the glob-arguments to make sure the search-pattern is using the correct OS separator (depending on the running OS):

```
import os
import glob

dirs = ['data', 'vitalstrike', 'user-site-export', 'data-*']
data_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(*dirs))
```

Output of dirs:

```
data/vitalstrike/user-site-export/data-*  # Mac/*nix
data\vitalstrike\user-site-export\data-*  # Windows
```